# Exponentials in python: x**y vs math.pow(x, y)

Tags: python, math, built-in, pow

Which one is more efficient using `math.pow` or the `**` operator? When should I use one over the other?

So far I know that `x**y` can return an `int` or a `float` if you use a decimal
the function `pow` will return a float

```
import math

print( math.pow(10, 2) )

print( 10. ** 2 )
```

Comment: Why not `timeit` to find out?

Comment: `timeit` shows that `math.pow` is slower than `**` in all cases.  What is `math.pow()` good for anyway?  Has anybody an idea where it can be of any advantage then?

Comment: @Alfe how did you measure, or do I misunderstand your `in all cases`? I [see cases](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28539821/2932052) where `math.pow` is much faster.

Comment: @Wolf, Do you?  Your link points to a comparison of `pow` with `math.pow`, but I'm talking about a comparison of `math.pow` with the `**` operator.  Your comparison there can be completed by adding that third version, then `**` again beats every other option: `import timeit; print timeit.timeit("math.pow(2, 100)",setup='import math'), timeit.timeit("pow(2, 100)"), timeit.timeit("2 ** 100")` → `0.170357942581 1.00546097755 0.013473033905`.

Comment: But I have to admit that the results are not exactly the same.  `math.pow` _always_ returns a `float` (also for `int` input) while `**` returns the type of its input (well, mixed input results in `float`).  But that's still no good reason to use `math.pow`, IMHO.

Comment: @Alfe [WOW](http://ideone.com/fDZeTZ) thanks for pointing out this detail. Is there a simple explanation (besides referring the source code)? ...maybe a good question for SO ;-) ?

Comment: @Alfe even if *an* answer is found to the question [Why is a**b so much faster than math.pow(a,b)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28563187/2932052) - and I really don't like to import math for pow - I'm not sure if there isn't something left. And *your* question (*`What is math.pow() good for anyway?`*) seems to be unanswered yet. Anyway, thanks a lot for your time :-)

Comment: Still investigating this, but answers here seem to be incomplete. I was doing some somewhat large cryptographic calculations, and while `4926601444670 ** 4235309647073 % 6000029000033` crashes the interpreter, `pow(4926601444670 , 4235309647073, 6000029000033)` is instantaneous.

Comment: Yeah, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133806/why-is-powa-d-n-so-much-faster-than-ad-n

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Using the power operator `**` will be faster as it won’t have the overhead of a function call. You can see this if you disassemble the Python code:

```
>>> dis.dis('7. ** i')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (7.0) 
              3 LOAD_NAME                0 (i) 
              6 BINARY_POWER         
              7 RETURN_VALUE         
>>> dis.dis('pow(7., i)')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (pow) 
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (7.0) 
              6 LOAD_NAME                1 (i) 
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            2 (2 positional, 0 keyword pair) 
             12 RETURN_VALUE         
>>> dis.dis('math.pow(7, i)')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (math) 
              3 LOAD_ATTR                1 (pow) 
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (7) 
              9 LOAD_NAME                2 (i) 
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            2 (2 positional, 0 keyword pair) 
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note that I’m using a variable `i` as the exponent here because constant expressions like `7. ** 5` are actually evaluated at compile time.

Now, in practice, this difference does not matter that much, as you can see when timing it:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit('7. ** i', setup='i = 5')
0.2894785532627111
>>> timeit('pow(7., i)', setup='i = 5')
0.41218495570683444
>>> timeit('math.pow(7, i)', setup='import math; i = 5')
0.5655053168791255
```

So, while `pow` and `math.pow` are about twice as slow, they are still fast enough to not care much. Unless you can actually identify the exponentiation as a bottleneck, there won’t be a reason to choose one method over the other if clarity decreases. This especially applies since [`pow`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) offers an integrated modulo operation for example.

---

Alfe asked a good question in the comments above:

> `timeit` shows that `math.pow` is slower than `**` in all cases. What is `math.pow()` good for anyway? Has anybody an idea where it can be of any advantage then?

The big difference of `math.pow` to both the builtin `pow` and the power operator `**` is that it *always* uses float semantics. So if you, for some reason, want to make sure you get a float as a result back, then `math.pow` will ensure this property.

Let’s think of an example: We have two numbers, `i` and `j`, and have no idea if they are floats or integers. But we want to have a float result of `i^j`. So what options do we have?

- We can convert at least one of the arguments to a float and then do `i ** j`.
- We can do `i ** j` and convert the result to a float (float exponentation is automatically used when either `i` or `j` are floats, so the result is the same).
- We can use `math.pow`.

So, let’s test this:

```
>>> timeit('float(i) ** j', setup='i, j = 7, 5')
0.7610865891750791
>>> timeit('i ** float(j)', setup='i, j = 7, 5')
0.7930400942188385
>>> timeit('float(i ** j)', setup='i, j = 7, 5')
0.8946636625872202
>>> timeit('math.pow(i, j)', setup='import math; i, j = 7, 5')
0.5699394063529439
```

As you can see, `math.pow` is actually faster! And if you think about it, the overhead from the function call is also gone now, because in all the other alternatives we have to call `float()`.

---

In addition, it might be worth to note that the behavior of `**` and `pow` can be overridden by implementing the special `__pow__` (and `__rpow__`) method for custom types. So if you don’t want that (for whatever reason), using `math.pow` won’t do that.

Comment: You got +1 for " the behavior of ** and pow can be overridden": If writting module, I am sure it very matters to prevent surprises comming from the user environment....

Answer (score 36):

The pow() function will allow you to add a third argument as a modulus.

For example: I was recently faced with a memory error when doing

> 2**23375247598357347582 % 23375247598357347583

Instead I did:

> `pow(2, 23375247598357347582, 23375247598357347583)`

This returns in mere milliseconds instead of the massive amount of time and memory that the plain exponent takes. So, when dealing with large numbers and parallel modulus, pow() is more efficient, however when dealing with smaller numbers without modulus, ** is more efficient.

Comment: The question isn't asking about built-in [`pow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow). It's asking about `math.pow(x, y)` vs `x ** y`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133806/why-is-powa-d-n-so-much-faster-than-ad-n, relevant here, was cited in comments above.

Answer (score 8):

Just for the protocol: The `**` operator is equivalent to the two-argument version of the [built-in `pow` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#pow), the `pow` *function* accepts an optional third argument (modulus) if the first two arguments are integers.

So, if you intend to calculate remainders from powers, use the built-in function. The `math.pow` will give you false results for arguments of reasonable size:

```
import math

base = 13
exp = 100
mod = 2
print math.pow(base, exp) % mod
print pow(base, exp, mod)
```

When I ran this, I got `0.0` in the first case which obviously cannot be true, because 13 is odd (and therefore all of it's integral powers). The `math.pow` version uses the limited accuracy of the [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) *Double precision* (52 bits mantissa, slightly less than 16 decimal places) which causes an error here.

For sake of fairness, we must say, `math.pow` *can* also be faster:

```py
>>> import timeit
>>> min(timeit.repeat("pow(1.1, 9.9)", number=2000000, repeat=5))
0.3063715160001266
>>> min(timeit.repeat("math.pow(1.1, 9.9)", setup="import math", number=2000000, repeat=5))
0.2647279420000359
```

The `math.pow` function had (and still has) its strength in engineering applications, but for number theoretical applications, you should use the built-in `pow` function.

---

Some online examples

- http://ideone.com/qaDWRd (wrong remainder with `math.pow`)
- http://ideone.com/g7J9Un (lower performance with `pow` on int values)
- http://ideone.com/KnEtXj (slightly lower performance with `pow` on float values)

---

**Update (inevitable correction):** 
I removed the timing comparison of `math.pow(2,100)` and `pow(2,100)` since `math.pow` gives a wrong result whereas, for example, the comparison between `pow(2,50)` and `math.pow(2,50)` would have been fair (although not a realistic use of the `math`-module function). I added a better one and also the details that cause the limitation of `math.pow`.

Answer (score 6):

`**` is indeed faster then `math.pow()`, but if you want a simple quadratic function like in your example it is even faster to use a product.

```
10.*10.
```

will be faster then

```
10.**2
```

The difference is not big and not noticable with one operation (using `timeit`), but with a large number of operations it can be significant.

Answer (score 4):

Well, they are for different tasks, really.

Use `pow` (equivalent to `x ** y` with two arguments) when you want integer arithmetic.

And use `math.pow` if either argument is float, and you want float output.

For a discussion on the differences between `pow` and `math.pow`, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10282674/674039).

Answer (score 0):

operator `**` (same as `pow()`) can be used to calculate very large integer number.

```
>>> 2 ** 12345
164171010688258216356020741663906501410127235530735881272116103087925094171390144280159034536439457734870419127140401667195510331085657185332721089236401193044493457116299768844344303479235489462...

>>> math.pow(2, 12345)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: math range error
```