# In Python, why does a negative number raised to an even power remain negative?

Tags: python, operator-precedence

In Python

```
>>> i = 3  
>>> -i**4  
-81
```

Why is `-i**4` not evaluated as `(-i)**4`, but as `-(i**4)`?

I suppose one could argue that raising to a power takes precedence over (implicit) multiplication of `i` with minus one (i.e. you should read `-1*i**4`). 
But where I learned math, `-i**n` with `n` even and `i` positive, should come out positive.

Comment: its about priority :)

Comment: You answered your own question.  Exponentiation has higher priority than multiplication.  If you learned that -1**2 = 1 in a mathematical context, you learned wrong.  (It is true that some programming languages do this, but they are also wrong in that they don't maintain the mathematical convention.)

Comment: it is apparent that the author is talking about a mathematical notation that does not use parentheses around the base number, and not about a specific language grammar. this is the notation that I learned as well. And in this notation, `-1^2` (using LaTex expression) is 1.

Comment: I still would say that that is incorrect as mathematical notation (as do most sources I can find; see for instance [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) and [here](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/53194.html)).  However, this is straying a bit from the question as it relates to Python; programming languages sadly don't always conform to established notational standards.

Comment: @BrenBarn Take a calculator, press 1, press the negative button, press the square button. What do you get? I get 1. I wonder if US notation is different than European, but never mind, I accept your point.

Comment: @RolfBly: On just about any calculator I've seen that has a square button, that will produce -1, because those are usually scientific-style calculators that handle the order of operations.  It's true that some calculators don't know about order of operations, though: on a simple "four-function", calculator, entering `2 + 3 X 4` will produce 20.

Comment: @brenbarn Try windows calculator. scientific mode.

Comment: @RolfBly: Sure, but my point is that order of operations is a concept that applies to *mathematical expressions*, not calculator buttons.  When you enter that into Windows calculator, you can see it doing `sqr(-1)` --- that is, the -1 is considered to be in parentheses.  A more apt choice would be [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-1^2), which is designed to work with mathematical expressions as such.

Comment: @brenbarn That's my point too. I read -x^2 as the square of a negative number (neg num * neg num = pos num). You read it as the negative square of a number. (num * num, but then with a minus in front). I'm currently checking on a Dutch math forum whether methods have changed (I'm a BsC in EE 1984), or whether they're different this side of the Atlantic.

Comment: @RolfBly: I'm curious to hear what they say.  I would find it stunning if `-x^2` is interpreted as `(-x)^2` when the exponent is written using normal notation (i.e., a superscript rather than `^`).  It would totally change how all polynomials have to be written.

Comment: @Brenbarn I'm happy to inform you that you are right and I was wrong. Thank you for the learning experience! This is the literal answer (translated by yours truly) from Wiskundeforum.nl (wiskunde is Dutch for Mathematics): "There is an essential difference between -a² = -1∙a² and (-a)² = -a∙-a = a², whereby -a² represents the opposite of a² and (-a)² represents the square of the opposite of a." So there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `**` operator binds more tightly than the `-` operator does in Python. If you want to override that, you'd use parentheses, e.g. `(-i)**4`.

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: this is imho a bad implementation.
if I write: -2 ** 2, I am stating the negative number to the power of 2, not the minus operator....

Answer (score 5):

You can use the pow() function from math.

```
import math
i = 3
math.pow(-i,4)
```

This will yield a positive value.

As stated here: [Exponentials in python x.**y vs math.pow(x, y)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969773/exponentials-in-python-x-y-vs-math-powx-y), this option (or just build in pow()) would be ideal if you want to always produce a float.

Comment: This is somewhat overkill for something that could be handled via parentheses - `(-i)**4`.

Comment: this might not necessarily be an overkill, it depends on the interpreter implementation, but the question is not about how to compute an exponent.

Answer (score 3):

The power operator (`**`) has a higher precedence than the unary negation (`-`) operator. `-i**4` is evaluated as `-(i**4)` - i.e., you take 3 up to the power of four, which is 81, and then negate it, resulting in `-81`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do (-i)**4 to get a positive result.

The *'s have higher priority than the '-'.

When in doubt, use parentheses. (or, as Amber suggested, refer to the language documentation)