# Cannot raise a negative value to the power of 0.2 without errors in python

Tags: python, numpy, math

I am trying to raise -48.08 to the power of 0.2 which should equal -2.17. However when trying to calculate this in python, every way I've tried, I cannot seem to arrive at that number.

Here are my attempted solutions:

```
math.pow(-48.08 , 0.2)
```

which gives the following error:

```
ValueError: math domain error
```

Another solution attempted was:

```
-48.08 ** 0.2
```

Which gives a complex number `197498009.35948756-143490702.9960685j`

Does anyone know a way in which I could achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: `(-48.08) ** 0.2` does not equal -2.17, but `-(48.08 ** 0.2)` does. Which of the two do you want?

Comment: "Which gives a complex number `197498009.35948756-143490702.9960685j`" Err. Are you _sure_ about that? Assuming that you meant `(-48.08) ** 0.2` rather than `-48.08 ** 0.2` (which is `-2.1696660420701677`), that complex result is _way_ too large. If you're really getting that result, that looks like a bug somewhere.

Comment: @NilsWerner I just did they both give the exact same on my calculator

Comment: @MarkDickinson I'm literally only using those numbers and doing as that, I get that complex number.

Comment: @gerardcslabs: Then something somewhere is very wrong. Can you post _exactly_ the code that you ran, and describe how you ran it? What version of Python are you using, and where did you get it from? Is this definitely CPython? Or some other flavour of Python? What platform? Are you running the code in a script, or directly in the Python interpreter?

Comment: @MarkDickinson thanks Mark but not to worry! The bottom solution seems to work for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Your second approach should work not sure if you are doing it correctly. Try this:

```
import math
-48.08 ** 0.2

Output:
-2.1696660420701677
```

However a point to note here is that `**` operator binds more tightly than the `-` operator in Python. If you want to override that, you'd use parentheses.

[Refer this](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726592/in-python-why-does-a-negative-number-raised-to-an-even-power-remain-negative) for complete details on the operator precedence

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

print(-(math.pow(48.08, 0.2)))
```

Maybe can help you?
In math (in python) you can't do that