# Why is 2**100 so much faster than math.pow(2,100)?

Tags: python, performance, pow

When discussing the question [Exponentials in python x.**y vs math.pow(x, y)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20969773/2932052), 
[Alfe stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969773/exponentials-in-python-x-y-vs-math-powx-y#comment31503032_20969773) that there would be no good reason for using `math.pow` instead of the builtin `**` operator in python.

> timeit shows that math.pow is slower than ** in all cases. What is math.pow() good for anyway? Has anybody an idea where it can be of any advantage then?

We tried to convince each other with some `timeit` arguments an he is the winner so far ;-) -- At least the following `timeit` results, seem to verify that *`math.pow is slower than ** in all cases`*.

```
import timeit
print timeit.timeit("math.pow(2, 100)",setup='import math')
print timeit.timeit("2.0 ** 100.0")
print timeit.timeit("2 ** 100")
print timeit.timeit("2.01 ** 100.01")
```

Output:

```
0.329639911652
0.0361258983612
0.0364260673523
0.0363788604736
```

([ideone-shortcut](http://ideone.com/fDZeTZ))

**Is there a simple explanation for the difference<sup>[1]</sup> we observe?**

---

<sup>[1]</sup> The performances of `math.pow` and `**` differ by one order of magnitude.

Edits:

- literal arguments instead of variables in title
- footnote that explicitly points on the magnitude of difference

Comment: This seems like a dupe of a question you linked to.

Comment: I believe the explanation is given in one of the answers in the link you gave. One of them disassembles each case, showing how the call is rendered.

Comment: @lurker No. It's no duplicate, look at the factor 9 instead of something like 1.2.

Comment: @user694733 I'm sure that this isn't a dup, I read the question and the answers before adding an answer myself to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969773/exponentials-in-python-x-y-vs-math-powx-y

Comment: Because you have constants I suspect the power is computed at compile time. Check the disassembly. If that's the case then you need something like `print timeit.timeit("2.0 ** i", setup='i=100.0')` to make a fair comparison.

Comment: @shuttle87 may have a point. Compare: `timeit.timeit('x ** y', setup='x, y = 2, 100')` with `timeit.timeit('math.pow(x, y)', setup='import math; x, y = 2, 100')`. Of course, that probably raises more questions than answers. ;)

Comment: @lurker and that's why I ask ;-)

Comment: Yep, and that's why I up-voted your question (+1). :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Essentially the reason that the power operator looks like it's doing so well in your examples is because Python has most likely [folded the constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) at compile time.

```
import dis
dis.dis('3.0 ** 100')    
i = 100
dis.dis('3.0 ** i')
```

This gives the following output:

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               2 (5.153775207320113e+47)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (3.0)
              3 LOAD_NAME                0 (i)
              6 BINARY_POWER
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

You can see this run here: http://ideone.com/5Ari8o

So in this case you can see it's not actually doing a fair comparison of the performance of the power operator vs `math.pow` because the result has been precomputed then cached. When you are making the `3.0 ** 100` there's no computation performed, the result is just being returned. This you would expect to be much faster than any exponentiation operation performed at runtime. This is ultimately what explains your results.

For a more fair comparison you need to force the computation to occur at runtime by using a variable:

```
print timeit.timeit("3.0 ** i", setup='i=100')
```

I tried making a quick benchmark for this using the python 3.4.1 on my computer:

```
import timeit
trials = 1000000
print("Integer exponent:")
print("pow(2, 100)")
print(timeit.timeit(stmt="pow(2, 100)", number=trials))
print("math.pow(2, 100)")
print(timeit.timeit(stmt="m_pow(2, 100)", setup='import math; m_pow=math.pow', number=trials))
print("2 ** 100")
print(timeit.timeit(stmt="2 ** i", setup='i=100', number=trials))
print("2.0 ** 100")
print(timeit.timeit(stmt="2.0 ** i", setup='i=100', number=trials))
print("Float exponent:")
print("pow(2.0, 100.0)")
print(timeit.timeit(stmt="pow(2.0, 100.0)", number=trials))
print("math.pow(2, 100.0)")
print(timeit.timeit(stmt="m_pow(2, 100.0)", setup='import math; m_pow=math.pow', number=trials))
print("2.0 ** 100.0")
print(timeit.timeit(stmt="2.0 ** i", setup='i=100.0', number=trials))
print("2.01 ** 100.01")
print(timeit.timeit(stmt="2.01 ** i", setup='i=100.01', number=trials))
```

results:

```
Integer exponent:
pow(2, 100)
0.7596459520525322
math.pow(2, 100)
0.5203307256717318
2 ** 100
0.7334983742808263
2.0 ** 100
0.30665244505310607
Float exponent:
pow(2.0, 100.0)
0.26179656874310275
math.pow(2, 100.0)
0.34543158098034743
2.0 ** 100.0
0.1768205988074767
2.01 ** 100.01
0.18460920008178894
```

So it looks like the conversion to a float eats up a fair amount of the execution time.

I also added a benchmark for `math.pow` note that this function is not the same as the builtin `pow` see this for more: [Difference between the built-in pow() and math.pow() for floats, in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282674/difference-between-the-built-in-pow-and-math-pow-for-floats-in-python)

Comment: A really great explanation. I finally tried `timeit.timeit("pass")` to see "the light" ;-)

Comment: @wolf, yes that's pretty much exactly what's going on here and explains the large time discrepancy.

Comment: Well, `pass` is even more efficient ;-) -- I tried something to make the comparison fair http://ideone.com/WxO0S7

Comment: So the answer is: It's not _so_ much faster as the first impression suggested (which was just due to the unnoticed folding).  But the core of the question remains:  Using `**` is always faster than using `math.pow` or using `pow`.  Is there any use of `pow` and expecially `math.pow` under these circumstances (unless you need modulo computation of `pow` of course)?

Comment: @Alfe check out http://ideone.com/WxO0S7 here you see that `math.pow` is faster for float **variables**. As expected. If you know a better answer, I'll be happy to accept *it* instead ;-)

Comment: @Wolf, sorry, I don't see such results there.  I tried my own: `timeit.timeit('mpow(a, b)', setup='from math import pow as mpow; a=2.; b=100')` and `timeit.timeit('a ** b', setup='from math import pow as mpow; a=2.; b=100')` and got `0.15636205673217773` and `0.12388300895690918` resp.  So still, `**` is faster for me.

Comment: @Wolf, your test regarding `indirect math.pow` (line 15) is buggy.  You import `math.pow` as `m`, so you are not using the local function `m` you defined before (so have an indirection less and it isn't comparable to `indirect builtin pow` above).  Maybe this triggered your wrong assumption that there is a case in which using `math.pow` is faster than using `**`.  Actually there isn't, it still seems, and I'd still like to know if there are other scenarios in which using `math.pow` can make sense.

Comment: @Alfe That's interesting. I think it's really the call that makes the difference (http://ideone.com/GEowHy). BTW: you're absolutely right, it's buggy, I'm trying to repair it.

Comment: Just use `from __main__ import m` without an `as` clause.  Then it (again) was much slower for me than the `**` version in `b()`.

Comment: [fixed] Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71090/discussion-between-wolf-and-alfe).

Comment: @Alfe it's not always true that `pow` or `math.pow` is faster than `**`. Sometimes it's the other way around. Compare: `timeit.timeit('x ** y', setup='x, y = 2, 100')` with `timeit.timeit('math.pow(x, y)', setup='import math; x, y = 2, 100')`.  I still think there are still some unanswered questions about the difference.

Comment: @lurker didn't you mix-up functions and operator?

Comment: @Wolf maybe :) I was just indicating that there's still a significant difference in performance (comparing like cases) between `**` and `pow`. Isn't that what the whole question is about? Maybe I misunderstood...