# Python 3.X: Why nb**3 is slower than nb*nb*nb

Tags: python, python-3.x, benchmarking

I'm trying to understand why 1 dedicate python function is slower than manual function.

I create a benchmark with timeit for 2 function.

I loop 100 times.

`nb**3` = ~28.166s

`nb*nb*nb` = ~10.529s

(using Python 3.5 on windows)

I don't understand why the operator created by python (power operator) take more time than other. The power operator is defined by Python and we dont need to add new function like `math.pow`.

```
def power_test():
    nb = 2;
    for i in range(100):
        b = nb**3

def repeat_test():
    nb = 2;
    for i in range(100):
        b = nb*nb*nb;


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print("start bench1");
    print(timeit.timeit("power_test()", setup="from __main__ import power_test"))
    print("end bench1\n");
    print("start Bench2");
    print(timeit.timeit("repeat_test()", setup="from __main__ import repeat_test"));
    print("end bench2\n");
```

full result:

```
start bench1
28.166055432365265
end bench1

start Bench2
10.52991797905926
end bench2
```

Thank you

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you swap the order of the tests?

Comment: Good question, it is the same result. the `nb*nb*nb` = 11s and `**` operator = "32s"

Comment: Python already has `math.pow` and a different built-in `pow`, and both are slower than `**`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20970087/2588818

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's something else happening here. If you try `timeit("2**3")` vs `timeit("2*2*2")` you'll see that there is hardly any difference.

Comment: yeah that's I think but I don't know really why I have this result.

Comment: Interestingly, I'm getting the exact opposite results on Python 2.7 :P

Comment: Hm I'll try to do it on 2.7