# Weird python power module result

Tags: python, modulus, exponent

According to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969773/exponentials-in-python-x-y-vs-math-powx-y) answers there is not difference between `pow(a,b)` and `a**b`. However, `math.pow(a,b)` returns a float value. Now, when running the following python code something strange happens:

```
>>>import math
>>>math.pow(19,13)%2537
2296.0
>>>pow(19,13)%2537
2299
```

These statements **should** give the same value but don't. Any clue as to why this happens?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282674/difference-between-the-built-in-pow-and-math-pow-for-floats-in-python

Comment: `pow(19,13)%2537` gives me `2299L` in Python 2.7, not 2599. Where's the extra 300 from?

Comment: @roganjosh Sorry, my bad. It's a typo.

Comment: @ZheHe 's link is quite informative but I don't think this question duplicates it. This question is partially about why the float value is significantly different than the integer value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `float` type looses precision. They are represented by the nearest binary fraction and from the docs [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#floating-point-arithmetic-issues-and-limitations)

> Interestingly, there are many different decimal numbers that share the
>   same nearest approximate binary fraction.

You can see the problem clearly with the result of `math.pow(19,13)` where multiple integers map to the same float.

```
>>> f = math.pow(19,13)
>>> float(int(f)) == float(int(f) - 1)
True
>>> float(int(f)) == float(int(f) - 2)
True
>>> float(int(f)) == float(int(f) - 3)
True
>>> float(int(f)) == float(int(f) - 4)
True
>>> float(int(f)) == float(int(f) - 5)
False
```

Since python can handle very large integers, try to stay away from floats!

Answer (score 1):

As you say `math.pow` returns a float value and `pow` does not.  Calling the modulo operator on a float will round it to an integer. Rounding floating point to integer will cause loss of precision.

```
>>> int(math.pow(19,13))
42052983462257056
>>> pow(19,13)
42052983462257059
```

Answer (score 0):

`math.pow()` converts its arguments to `float`:

```
>>> import math
>>> import fractions
>>> math.pow(fractions.Fraction(3, 2), 2)
2.25
```

but the built-in `pow` does not:

```
>>> pow(fractions.Fraction(3, 2), 2)
Fraction(9, 4)
```

Also check: [Difference between the built-in pow() and math.pow() for floats, in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282674/difference-between-the-built-in-pow-and-math-pow-for-floats-in-python)