# Is my Sieve of Eratosthenes implemented correctly? (Python)

Tags: python, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I need to generate a large number of prime numbers, however it is taking far too long using the Sieve of Eratosthenes. Currently it takes roughly 3 seconds to generate primes under 100,000 and roughly 30 for primes under 1,000,000. Which seems to indicate an O(n) complexity but as far as I know that's not right. Code:

```
def generate_primes(limit):
    boolean_list = [False] * 2 + [True] * (limit - 1)
    for n in range(2, int(limit ** 0.5 + 1)):
        if boolean_list[n] == True:
            for i in range(n ** 2, limit + 1, n):
                boolean_list[i] = False
```

Am I missing something obvious? How can I improve the performance of the sieve?

Comment: If your algorithm is O(n) congratulations, it's faster than any known implementation (it's usually O(n log log n) according to the Wikipedia page). But it's not clear why that's a problem.

Comment: `if boolean_list[n] == True:` => `if boolean_list[n]:` apart from that I don't see how it could be improved

Comment: maybe use `numpy` to set to false with vectorized indices to avoid the inner loop?

Comment: use an integer set instead of list?

Comment: @Denziloe Maybe I've misunderstood the time complexity for it. I was under the assumption that the Sieve of Eratosthenes was meant to run faster and I wasn't sure if there was a mistake with my implementation of it

Comment: @danjedwards123 Faster than what?

Comment: @Denziloe Just in general. Are there any quicker ways to generate large primes?

Comment: n ** 2 => n * n

Comment: is it correct btw? n ** 2 looks suspitious

Comment: @danjedwards123 Yes, I'm sure there are faster ways than Eratosthenes. Is your implementation of Eratosthenes worryingly slow? I don't see any reason to think so. Python is a high-level language and iterating in Python can often be around 100 times slower than using a lower-level language such as C. If you want to use Python you might want to look into `numpy` which provides an interface to fast arrays written in C.

Comment: @Serge They are the same in this case as ** is the power operator

Comment: @danjedwards123 I ran your code basically unchanged on a Raspberry pi 1 model B, no overclocking and got 0.6 seconds and 6.65 seconds respectively for limits 10^5 and 10^6. Are you perhaps trying it out in debugging mode in an IDE? that could add delays on each iteration and this code has lots of them

Comment: use xrange for speed

Comment: tried n * n, 2ms improvement on my pc!

Comment: xrange has no advantage over range in python3, I think

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Is this correct?” an off topic question, and what should I ask instead?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359466/why-is-is-this-correct-an-off-topic-question-and-what-should-i-ask-instead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop indexing is well known in Python to be an incredibly slow operation. By replacing a loop with array slicing, and a list with a Numpy array, we see increases @ 3x:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

def generate_primes_original(limit):
    boolean_list = [False] * 2 + [True] * (limit - 1)
    for n in range(2, int(limit ** 0.5 + 1)):
        if boolean_list[n] == True:
            for i in range(n ** 2, limit + 1, n):
                boolean_list[i] = False
    return np.array(boolean_list,dtype=np.bool)

def generate_primes_fast(limit):

    boolean_list = np.array([False] * 2 + [True] * (limit - 1),dtype=bool)
    for n in range(2, int(limit ** 0.5 + 1)):
        if boolean_list[n]:
            boolean_list[n*n:limit+1:n] = False
    return boolean_list

limit = 1000

print(timeit.timeit("generate_primes_fast(%d)"%limit, setup="from __main__ import generate_primes_fast"))
# 30.90620080102235 seconds

print(timeit.timeit("generate_primes_original(%d)"%limit, setup="from __main__ import generate_primes_original"))
# 91.12803511600941 seconds

assert np.array_equal(generate_primes_fast(limit),generate_primes_original(limit))
# [nothing to stdout - they are equal]
```

To gain even more speed, one option is to use [numpy vectorization](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html). Looking at the outer loop, it's not immediately obvious how one could vectorize that.

Second, you will see dramatic speed-ups if you port to [Cython](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html#numpy-tutorial), which should be a fairly seamless process.

Edit: you may also see improvements by changing things like `n**2 => math.pow(n,2)`, but minor improvements like that are inconsequential compared to the bigger problem, which is the iterator.

Comment: `math.pow` is quite a bit slower than using the exponent operator, actually. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969773/exponentials-in-python-x-y-vs-math-powx-y

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I wasn't expecting such an improvement, and I'll look into the other two recommendations you gave.

Comment: @mypetlion - that's interesting, I didn't know that. It always surprises me how high the overhead for function calls is. Thanks!

Comment: @danjedwards123 - good luck! If speed is critically important and you don't want to move to a compiled language, try checking out Julia - it's an insanely fast JIT language that is perfectly suited for this usecase :)

Answer (score 0):

If your are still using Python 2 use xrange instead of range for greater speed