# Why is math.pow returning different values than the ** operator?

Tags: python

I've been trying to solve this problem:

> The cube at the bottom will have a volume of n^3, the cube above will
>   have volume of (n-1)^3 and so on until the top which will have a
>   volume of 1^3.
>
> You are given the total volume m of the building. Being given m can
>   you find the number n of cubes you will have to build?

And this is my code

```
import math

def find_nb(m):

nb = 1
nb_vol = 0

while True:
    nb_vol += math.pow(nb, 3)

    if (nb_vol == m):
        return nb
    elif (nb_vol > m):
        return -1

    nb += 1
```

Now, when I try to solve for find_nb(2521115597681328384) it returns -1 when it should in fact return 56352. If I change

```
nb_vol += math.pow(nb, 3)
```

to

```
nb_vol += nb ** 3
```

Everything works correctly. **Why?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exponentials in python x.\*\*y vs math.pow(x, y)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969773/exponentials-in-python-x-y-vs-math-powx-y)

Comment: @Reznik That question talks more about performance than correctness.

Comment: for completeness go here to check if two floats are close enough to be called equal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python

Comment: @Anonymous The question itself answers this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`math.pow` [always converts it’s arguments to `float`s first](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/math.html#math.pow), which are only approximations.

The `**` operator uses integers that can never overflow, which means that it always gives a correct result.