# Exponents in python: df**x vs df.pow(x)

Tags: python, pandas

Just out of curiosity, what is the difference between `df**x` and `df.pow(x)`?

Having a dataframe `df` with a column named `values` you can either do: `df.values ** 2` or `df.values.pow(2)` to compute the entire column to the power of 2. I understand that you can change the axis while using `DataFrame.pow`. But is there a difference in performance? Will changing the power influence the performance?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1.,2])
df**2
df.pow(2)
```

I have read the discussion between the difference between `x**y` and `x.pow(y)` from the `math`-module [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969773/exponentials-in-python-xy-vs-math-powx-y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pow.html):

> Equivalent to dataframe ** other, but with support to substitute a fill_value for missing data in one of the inputs. With reverse version, rpow.

It seems that performance wise they are nearly equivalent, but `pow` allows you to change the axis and add a `fill_value` which replaces missing values. I'd imagine that there is an extremely slight performance cost to using `pow`, but if a performance difference that granular matters, maybe python and pandas are the wrong tools for your project.

Comment: Ah I missed that, thanks!