# Why is pow(x,y,z) useful in python?

Tags: python

In python, `pow(x,y,z)` is equivalent to `(x**y)%z`, and the former is more efficient than the latter. But why is it useful? In which context does one routinely need to calculate such a quantity (or at least routinely enough for python developers to include it in the language)?

Comment: RSA encryption requires computing the value of large products modulo a given number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is famously useful for the [RSA algorithm](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(algorithm)). If you try to use `x**y%z` to encrypt or decrypt a message using RSA, it will be very slow or you could run out of memory, because `x**y` is large.

Comment: might be useful to add: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133806/why-is-powa-d-n-so-much-faster-than-ad-n